Abraham Halevi (?) Messianic Prophecy for 5481?
Chevre,
I have come across a passage from the Historical Register which tells of the case of a false Messiah called Felix Coen, who was elected "king" on the basis of a certain "Abraham of the tribe of Levi", and who argued for the redemption to be brought about in the Jewish year 5481, i.e. 1721, according to an unclear calculation: add 3533 years (I have corrected the source below that mistakenly reads 4333 rather than 3533) since "the birth of Abraham", i.e. 1948 + 3533 = 5481, i.e. 1721.

That the prophecy was wrong is obvious, since we live in a much worse world, especially after 7/10. However, I suppose that this "Abraham of the tribe of Levi" could well be our Abraham ben Eliezer Halevi (?) but his messianic calculations do not include anything close to these numbers. Assuming this is reasonable, how do you think they came up with the odd number 3533 and the even odder calculation of counting "from the birth of Abraham"? I have also noticed that both 3533 and 5481 were Jubilee years but I don't really know how to solve this.
[EDIT]
After doing some supplementary research myself, I can confirm that this event was connected to an obscure blood accusation in Ferrara. where Felix Coen lived as a wealthy business man (he died in 1738).
The source is “The Historical Register," 1721 (here).
My interest here only focuses on the calculation of the 5481 as a messianic year by adding 1948 (Abraham's birth) to 3533 (Jubilee) on account of “Abraham Levi"'s prophecy.
I found NO evidence elsewhere of such calculation and such use of Abraham's birthday with messianic implications. Might it be something Sabbatean?
Az, todah rabbah le-kulkhem!

When did this Felix live? Perhaps he just punted the redemption to some time in the future?

Welcome to Me Yodeya! Your question needs additional information to comply with the site guidelines. Could you please add a source, reason for your correction, and possible helpful other thoughts? Thank you.

Welcome to MiYodeya Shlomo and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

The phrase "of the tribe of Levi" can also mean that he was a Kohen.

After some searching, it seems that several books reference a 1721 blood libel in Ferrara. Only one book that I've seen so far actually cites a source, but I can't access the page with the footnote to see the source (though there's a good chance that it's simply to the Encyclopedia Judaica, which doesn't cite a source). This makes it difficult to know who are the figures involved in this story (R' Avraham and Felix), but I'll keep searching.

The coming of moshiyach is tied to Sabbatical years (Shmitah) as in Megilla 17b https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.17b.13?lang=bi

If you found the answer, post it here as an answer yourself and accept it so that future users will see it as a question with an answer.
